# Cannot uninstall Podman from CentOS 8

Tags: docker, centos, podman

I have podman installed on a CentOS 8 machine. I want to switch to Docker so need to remove podman first because it conflicts with Docker.
However, when I try to remove it I get this:

```
Error:
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: dnf, systemd, systemd-udev
```

Tried this and it didn't work:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/eam/4.2?topic=questions-troubleshooting-tips#uninstall_podman

buildah is not even installed

Tried with both yum and dnf - no go

Comment: you might want to add the command that you tried and some supporting information about the system you're on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solved by adding --allowerasing

```
sudo yum install docker-ce.x86_64 --allowerasing
```